# ODBC Not Working After Code Compile

Tags: vb6

I have an application that reads an Access ODBC string from a file to connect to an access database. The app is compiled in XP (cannot be compiled in Win 7) and the installed on Windows 7. In the VB IDE, it works fine. However, as soon as its moved to Win7 (where I also define a System DSN to the C drive as I did with XP), it cannot connect to the database. The error:

**[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

I cannot test the compiled version in Win XP as it cannot be added to the domain I am working with.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try ideas from http://superuser.com/questions/465734/system-dsn-vs-user-dsn

Comment: You did create the DSN as a 32-bit DSN on Windows 7, not a 64-bit one?

Comment: @MarkJ Yes, 32 bit DSN

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: Apps that read database strings from a file stored in Program files must be ran with admin privileges.